# elasticsearch bulk processor failure

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bigdata

I want to index a large batch of index requests to 60 different indices(about 1000 million pieces,indices' name are like `boss-log-yyyy-MM-dd`).

Here is my java code:

```
List<IndexRequest> indexRequesList = bossMockDataService.indexRequestGenerator(batch); //generate random mock data.
    indexRequesList.forEach(indexRequest -> {
        bulkProcessor.add(indexRequest);
    });
    try {
       return bulkProcessor.awaitClose(30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

And here is my bulk processor:

```
@Override
public BulkProcessor initESbulkProcessor(RestHighLevelClient client) {
    Settings settings = Settings.EMPTY;
    ThreadPool threadPool = new ThreadPool(settings); // I have no Idea what the 'settings' object is.
    BulkProcessor.Listener listener = new BulkProcessor.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void beforeBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request) {
            int numberOfActions = request.numberOfActions();
            logger.debug("Executing bulk [{}] with {} requests", executionId, numberOfActions);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, BulkResponse response) {

            if (response.hasFailures()) {
                logger.warn("Bulk [{}] executed with failures", executionId);
            } else {
                logger.debug("Bulk [{}] completed in {} milliseconds", executionId, response.getTook().getMillis());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterBulk(long executionId, BulkRequest request, Throwable failure) {

            logger.error("Failed to execute bulk", failure);
        }

    };
    BulkProcessor.Builder builder = new BulkProcessor.Builder(client::bulkAsync, listener, threadPool);
    BulkProcessor bulkProcessor = builder.build();
    builder.setBulkActions(2000); 
    builder.setBulkSize(new ByteSizeValue(10L, ByteSizeUnit.MB));
    builder.setConcurrentRequests(10);
    builder.setFlushInterval(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(10L));
    builder.setBackoffPolicy(BackoffPolicy.constantBackoff(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(1L), 3));
    logger.info("bulk processor build complete!");
    return bulkProcessor;

}
```

It seems some data index request failed.The log is like:

```
2017-11-15 16:42:24 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [96] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:24 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [97] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:24 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [98] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:24 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [99] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:24 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [100] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:24 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [101] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:24 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [102] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:24 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [103] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:25 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [104] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:25 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [105] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:25 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [106] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:25 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [107] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:25 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [108] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:25 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [109] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:25 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [110] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:26 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [111] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:26 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [112] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:26 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [113] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:26 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [114] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:26 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [115] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:26 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [116] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:26 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [117] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:27 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [118] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:27 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [119] executed with failures
2017-11-15 16:42:27 [I/O dispatcher 1] WARN  BossMockDataServiceImpl:220 - Bulk [120] executed with failures
```

My situation:

- New to ES.
- 1 million pieces of data per day need to be stored and queried.
- Yet I have not configured my shard/replica/node/cluster,they are default now.
- When I use MySQL,I create a new partition for a day's data.
- The limit for MySQL is 60 days.The IO operation is getting more and more slow.

My goal:

- Easy to maintain my ES.
- Fast query,update and aggregation.
- Store 60+ days data.
- No tolerance for bulk request failure.(Seems some data lost above)

What I wonder is :

- Is it a good idea to create new index for a day's data ? Or I put them in one index?
- Why the bulk processor call back is failure ? How to fix it ?
- Is it necessary to create more cluster/node ? Where should I begin?